# read write ios issue in application start

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I added text file to the mainbundle and I write line on it to control the opening of my application like this

```
NSString *fileName =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestCases" ofType:@"txt"];

NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                                                usedEncoding:nil
                                                       error:nil];

if ([content length] == 0 ) {


    [self MoveAndBuild ];

}


content = @"Downloaded";
[content writeToFile:fileName 
          atomically:NO 
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
               error:nil];
```

what is supossed is that [self MoveAndBuild ]; be called just one time after installing the application , but it be called every time the application be opened , am I missing something

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in your application's bundle are read only. I'd use NSUserDefaults in your case. E.g.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Then you can read a value with

```
BOOL downloaded = [prefs boolForKey:@"downloaded"]
```

And write with

```
[prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"downloaded"];
```

Comment: could u give me more details , where I will save the data that will be checcked

Comment: That's all you need and it should be fine. More info here http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: what's the default value at the beginning

Comment: boolForKey returns NO if the key wasn't found, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
[content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

will never be successful because fileName points to the app bundle, which is non writable. So you are testing against the same file all the time.

If you would have used proper error handling you would have seen that.

```
NSError *error;
if (![content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing - %@", error);
}
```

btw. `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` is not a valid encoding